# sending data to php via jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send form data to php file using jquery 
but when I press the button to send this data there is nothing to be happen

the jquery code is

```html
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#daily_user_but").click(function(){
    //event.preventDefault();
        
    $('#result').html('<img src="images/ajax_loader_red_128.gif"/>');
 var jusername = $('#usernamed').val();
 var jpassword = $('#passwordd').val();
 var jadsoyad=$('#adsoyadd').val();
        var jtcno = $('#tcnod').val();
        var jtelefon = $('#telefond').val();
        var jmir=$('#mirror_field').val();
 
        //syntax - $.post('filename', {data}, function(response){});
 $.post('save.php',{id: "NewDailyUser", username:jusername, password:jpassword,tcno:jtcno,telefon:jtelefon,expair:jmir,adsoyad:jadsoyad},function(res){
  $('#result').html(res);
 });
    });
});
```

the code of save.php where the data is sent is

```html
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
elseif($id =="NewDailyUser"){
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 //$op=$_POST['op'];
 //$value=$_POST['value'];
// $tip=$_POST['tip'];
 $telefon=$_POST['telefon'];
 $tcno=$_POST['tcno'];
 $adsoyad=$_POST['adsoyad'];
 $expair=$_POST['mirror_field'];
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
 
 
 echo($expair);
 
 
 $bas=mysql_query("insert into radcheck (username,attribute,op,value,telefon,sifre,tcno,adsoyad) values ('$username','Cleartext-Password',':=','$password','$telefon','$password','$tcno','$adsoyad'),('$username','Expiration',':=','$expair','$telefon','$password','$tcno','$adsoyad') ") or die(mysql_error());
 if($bas){
   echo "assda";
  //header("location:Message.php?id=Basarili");
 } else {
  echo("dsdasdsa");
  header("location:Message.php?id=Hata");
 }
 
}
```

Comment: any error you are getting in console

Comment: no there is nothing

Comment: what is inside save.php?

Comment: there is acode to insert data into database

Comment: `save.php` is under same package?

Comment: show your `save.php`

Comment: For starters, make sure your php script sends a response, just print "hello"; at the top of your php script and check if you get that response.

Comment: What is status of the request in browser dev tools network? Did you add any error handling? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I edited my question and inserted the code of save.php

Comment: You dont have pass `mirror_field` So there will be undefined index error in php for `$expair=$_POST['mirror_field'];` Change it to `$expair=$_POST['expair'];`

Comment: I edited it and send the variable mirror_field but without result in other hand there was same code to send data it was working fine but now not working I don't know why

Comment: clear everything in your save.php and just leave a simple `echo "hello world";` and see if that is displayed

Comment: it same there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) its very easy to use

**Example:**

```
<!-- Get processed form result -->
<div id="resultOfMyProcessedForm"></div>

<!-- Your Form -->
<form action="path/to/save.php" method="
post" id="myForm">
    <!-- Form content will go here -->
</form>

<!-- include reuired libraries -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.1/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha256-8G/BdtcUMWw3c6j5nBvVtzaoj3sq/kX6xNN2FQ0w0MY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Script to process your form -->
<script>
  $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(response){
    $('#resultOfMyProcessedForm').html(response);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying problem? You just suggested another way of performing an ajax request.